# How do you algebraically prove $\frac{6+n}{(n+2)^2} > \frac{1}{n}$ for $n \ge 3$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $a_n=\frac{6+n}{(n+2)^2}$
Let $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$

I know that $a_n > b_n$ for $n \ge 3$ just by graphing

$f(x)=\frac{6+x}{(x+2)^2}$ and $g(x)=1/x$

But how do I prove $a_n > b_n$ for $n \ge 3$ algebraically?

Comment: Since $n$ is going to be positive, how about proving the related inequality $6n+n^2>(n+2)^2$ arrived at by cross-multiplying the fractions and recognizing that since $n$ is positive the sign doesn't change direction.  Next, recognize that $(n+2)^2 = n^2+4n+4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all to the left. You’ll have

$\frac{2n-4}{n(n+2)^2}>0$. Obviously true for $n>2$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a_n>b_n$ iff
$$
n(6+n)>(n+2)^2\iff 6n+n^2>n^2+4n+4\iff n>2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{6+n}{(n+2)^2} > \frac{1}{n} \Leftrightarrow \frac{(6+n)n-(n+2)^2}{n(n+2)^2}>0 \Leftrightarrow (6+n)n-(n+2)^2>0
$$
since $n \geq 3 >0$. Now
$$
(6+n)n-(n+2)^2=6n+n^2-n^2-4n-4=2n-4>0
$$
when $n>2$.